# Incompatible element type Set<String> for colection of System.SelectOption

Tags: apex

How to assign a set to List... I am getting the following error ..

Incompatible element type Set for collection of System.SelectOption

```
public List<SelectOption> cpOptions {
        get {
            if (cpOptions== null) {
                cpOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
            }
            return cpOptions ;
        }
        set;
        }

    public Set<String> cpOptions1{
        get {
            if (cpOptions1== null) {
                cpOptions1= new Set<String>();
            }
            return cpOptions1;
        }
        set;
        }

             cpOptions.add(cpOptions1);
             cpOptions1.add(cp1.Emp__c);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `addAll` method in the List Class: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm.

You are going to have another problem though because your `Set` and `List` are not of the same data type. You probably want to be converting your `Set<String>` to a `List<String>` after it has been constructed and loop over it to add new `SelectOption` instances to your `List<SelectOption>`.